# How to create additional start up script for one service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, init-script

I installed the package 'gearman-job-server' in Ubuntu server. it creates start up script by default as `/etc/init/gearman-job-server.conf`. But I want to add more command to same service. So created my custom start script as `/etc/init/gearmand.conf`, with below content. But unfortunately it's not running, when I restart the service (`service gearman-job-server restart`). So can someone tell me how to hook the custom start up script to the same service.

```
description "Gearmand Server"

start on started mysql
stop on runlevel [016]

kill timeout 3

respawn

exec gearmand \
--log-file=/var/log/gearmand.log \
--queue-type=MySQL \
--mysql-host=localhost \
--mysql-port=3306 \
--mysql-user=example \
--mysql-password=example01 \
--mysql-db=gearman \
--mysql-table=gearman_queue \
2>> /var/log/gearmand.log
```